# Android development with Netbeans IDE

Tags: android, netbeans

Has anybody had any success with developing for Android platform using Netbeans (5.5+ ) IDE? I know of atleast netbeans one plugin that is supposed to support it but wanted to hear if anyone is using netbeans for Android development and how easy it is to set it up.

Comment: Android Programming in Netbeans:
http://www.techjail.net/starting-programming-for-android-with-netbeans.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a project called nbandroid (formerly called undroid) which is a Netbeans version of ADT and it works quite fine with SDK 1.0

http://nbandroid.org/

In the past it was hosted at undroid.nolimit.cz and nbandroid.kenai.com, both these sites are obsolete now.

Comment: The two are different projects. 'undroid' is no more under development. The development has shifted to the latter. More instructions here at http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans. I have updated it to work with the current Android SDK.

Best!

Comment: As of Oct 2011, the instructions for installing the plugin are here:http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/pages/Install

Comment: See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVSk_WDI-yY for a video of how to mix nbandroid and Maven.

Comment: site is down is there anyway that i can get nbandroid?

Answer (score 8):

Android was built with the Eclipse IDE in mind.

It can work with any IDE, but if you don't have any strong feelings towards NetBeans you're probably better off developing for it with Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

http://nbandroid.org/ and (with sources hosted at https://bitbucket.org/nbandroid/nbandroid) will help you.

This project is a continuation of the first attempt originally published at undroid.ulimit.cz.

-Radim