# Are there any drawbacks of developing for Android in NetBeans?

Tags: android, ide

All Android developers I know use Eclipse. But I got used to NetBeans developing some web applications. Now, when I want to try Android development, I want to know if NetBeans is a good choice for that. I've searched for the NetBeans' plugin description, the first [post](http://www.nbandroid.org/2011/12/were-alive.html) I found started with a phrase "We're alive!", which made me wonder if they are really. So, this is the question. Is developing for Android in NetBeans a good option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developing Android in NetBeans or even from command prompt is possible.

But Android is best pair with Eclipse which is recommended by Google for Android App Development.

To develop in netbeans pleas look at this link:

[Android development with Netbeans IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365880/android-development-with-netbeans-ide)

Comment: Thanks, comparison of NetBeans with a command prompt and a Google's recommendation made the choice easy to make.